# Python combine 2 lists of strings for CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have two lists that I want to combine for csv output:

```
alist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
blist = ['d', 'e', 'f']
```

However, I want the output for the csv to format like this:

```
clist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd e f']
```

such that the last entry extended of the list contains the list of "blist", but will not be comma separated.  Unfortunately, what I have been trying instead gives me:

```
clist =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'def']
```

Comment: That gives me: clist=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] which is not quite right either.  I want the 4th entry to be ['d' 'e' 'f'].

Comment: Show your code on how you got your incorrect output.

Comment: Given python syntax, 'x' 'y' 'z' == 'xyz'.

Comment: as mentioned by julien ,
>>> clist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' 'e' 'f']
>>> print clist
['a', 'b', 'c', 'def']
in case you want to store in csv , use regex

Comment: For some reason I wasn't getting the space in-between def before when I tried the .join.  I may have not entered something correctly.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
 clist = alist + [" ".join(blist)]
```

otherwise I think what you are after doesn't make sense, or you need to explain better what you want... Given python syntax, `'x' 'y' 'z'` **is** `'xyz'`.

Comment: That gives me: clist=['a', 'b', 'c', 'def'] which is not quite right.

Comment: there's a space between the quotes... this gives `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd e f']`. If this is not what you want, then what you want is non sense.

Comment: x, y, and z are pulling fields from a database, so when I have them in the list I want their entries to remain separate, but stay in one field (separated by a space) when I write that row to the csv file in such a way that it doesn't get comma separated.

Comment: I am so sorry...your answer was correct.  That was what I was looking for.  I am getting ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd e f'] like you said.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: ok no worries, I've edited your question to reflect what you actually wanted, because as you wrote it it did not make sense... You can accept the answer if that fixed your problem.